# database/sql.convertAssignRows memory leak

Tags: go

when i use gorm and call Find method, then memory leaked.

```golang
func (mp *message) ListMessage(ctx context.Context, ci *ClientInfo) ([]Message, error) {

    tx := mp.db.WithContext(ctx).Raw(sql)
    var mss []MessageSource
    err := tx.Find(&mss).Error
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return mss, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the question you asked but I'm gonna try to help you anyway. Let me share a code snippet that shows how I usually use the `Raw` and `Find` methods. Then, I'm gonna walk you through all of the relevant sections.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Message struct {
    gorm.Model
    Description string
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(&Message{})
    defer db.Exec(`DELETE FROM "messages"`)

    db.Create(&Message{Description: "first"})
    db.Create(&Message{Description: "second"})
    db.Create(&Message{Description: "third"})

    var messages []Message
    // get data with SQL raw
    if err := db.Model(&Message{}).Raw(`SELECT * FROM "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."id"`).Scan(&messages).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("printed with SQL Raw...")
    for _, v := range messages {
        fmt.Println(v.Description)
    }
    fmt.Println(strings.Repeat("#", 100))
    var messages2 []Message
    // get data with Find method
    if err := db.Model(&Message{}).Find(&messages2).Error; err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("printed with Find...")
    for _, v := range messages2 {
        fmt.Println(v.Description)
    }
}
```

This code is mainly divided into three parts.

##### Beginning

In this phase, you can see the model I used for the example (`Message`). Then, I opened a connection to the local Postgres DB I ran through Docker. Lastly, I invoked the `Automigrate` method to sync the struct (or model) definition to the table in the DB and inserted three dummy records.

##### The `Raw` + `Scan` method

With this option, you are allowed to manually specify the query you wish to run against the underlying DB. The query is actually done when you invoke the `Scan` method which expects a variable to map results onto (e.g. the `messages` variable). Please note that you can also parameterize the statement with the `?` symbol.

##### The `Find` method

Instead, the `Find` method expects as the first parameter the variable to map results onto. Then, it also expects a condition to using for record filtering. If not provided it means that you'd like to get all of the records present in the table specified by the `Model` method.

If you're gonna stick to these approaches you shouldn't get any errors or warnings complaining about memory leaks. Let me know whether this helps you to figure out your problems or if I missed something, thanks!